# Form Validation in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my view i have

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit="return 
 validateForm(this);", name = "frm", id = "frm" }))
```

and in my JS file i have this code

```
function validateForm(form) {
alert("Called")
var x = form[model.username].value;
if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
}
```

When i use just an alert in the JS, it works. However when i pass in the form, even if the username is blank, the rest of the data is submitted. Am using ASP MVC 5

any ideas please?

Comment: Are you alerts still showing?  Is there an error in the browser's debugging console?  When you debug this in the browser, what is the value of `x`?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined at validateForm at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Comment: Then your `model` variable is not defined.  Are you trying to use server-side code in your client-side code?  What specifically do you expect `model.username` to be in that context and why?  If you're trying to get the value of an input in your JavaScript code, what is that input?

Comment: that is "model" in the js code posted

Comment: Why in the world are you not decorating your model properties with validation attributes (e.g. `[Required]`) and using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so that your get client side and server side validation out of the box (anyone can override that script and post back whatever bad/corrupt data they want!)

Comment: I suggest you read [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation) and learn some basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that `model.username` contains **`"johndoe123"`**. That value is then used, meaning that in fact you are requesting **`form["johndoe123"].value`** which I think is pretty unlikely to return a value. It may even produce an error, especially if either `model` or `model.username` are undefined.

You probably meant to request a form field that has **name="username"** or something like that, so I'll give an example on how to do that:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("theForm");
console.log(form);
console.log(form["username"]);
console.log(form["username"].value);
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="something">
</form>
```